# RowIndex of Gridview Error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I am implementing the bulk delete functionality with the help of Checkbox. But when I call the ID like below

```
string Id = grdUser.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

I get the error as

> System.EventArgs does not contain a definition of `RowIndex`.

I dont know why it is happening. Please see my code for your reference:-

```
 protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in grdUser.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)grdUser.FindControl("chkDelete");
            if (chkDelete.Checked)
            {
                string Id = grdUser.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Do let me know what changes I have to make

Comment: Delete button is outside of gridview, and there is a checkbox to mark for a deletion in each grid view row, right?

Comment: @Andrei: Yes you are right.

Comment: @BenRobinson: I want to delete the records that too in bulk using button Click

Comment: use gvRow.RowIndex instead of e.RowIndex

Comment: @RahulSutar, then this all looks like a `RowCommand` code copied into `Click` handler. Make sure you understand what event you are handling. A hint: why do you iterate over rows without using `gvRow` anywhere?

Comment: @Andrei: So what would be best possible approach to achieve this ?

Comment: @Sandeep: I implmented that, but i m getting error as `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at ` if (chkDelete.Checked)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `gvRow.RowIndex` as stated by Sandeep.

Then you have to bind your gridview somewhat like this.

```
 protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in grdUser.Rows)
        {
            if (gvRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("chkDelete");
                if (chkDelete.Checked)
                {
                    string Id = grdUser.DataKeys[gvRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                    DeleteRecordByID(Id);
                }
            }
        }

       //Bind your Gridview here
    }
```

Let me know if it works or not

Comment: `Bind Gridview` means I have to call the function where my default gridview is called on page_load right ?

Comment: @RahulSutar: Yes, exactly. you got it

Comment: Rahul: glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

you can Use Below Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < grdUser.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //Your logic and use   grdUser.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString();
      for delete


}
```