# Can't access DataGridViewCellEventArgs

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to extract the cell value from a DataGridView.

I created an event for CellClick and I get:

```
private void dataGridView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
}
```

But I need a `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`, rather than `EventArgs` to access `e.RowIndex`.

Not sure what am I missing. In every tutorial, I've seen the event is registered as `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` automatically. Any hints?

Comment: Checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/27566544/4636715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the `CellClick` event, not the `Click` event:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick?view=netframework-4.8